# Decoupling on PCB - Filled Zones or Traces

Tags: pcb, design, layout, decoupling

Which of the two following PCB layouts for the given schematics (7805 voltage regulator) is better? Do filled zones affect filter/decoupling capacitors negatively?

Thanks!

**Update:** Second layer is a ground plane.

#### Schematics

[image: Schematics]

#### Variant 1 (Filled Zones)

[image: Variant 1]

#### Variant 2 (Traces)

[image: Variant 2]

Comment: That schematic and this questions tell me you take decoupling serious. So, don't use an ancient voltage regulator. Modern voltage regulators have better regulation, and hence achieve cleaner / stabler output voltage with less capacitors. The heatsink, and the 12 V input voltage tells me that for the price of your capacitors, you could realistically have built a switch-mode step-down supply, to, say, 6V, and followed that with a lower-voltage drop linear regulator that's lower noise than the LM7805, thereby saving your the thermal problems you'll have.

Comment: Regarding the traces: unless your 12 V is really really unreliable, your capacitors are overkill and slightly thicker traces would work exactly as well as a plane, no clear preference.

Comment: I don't see how these are equivalent, how in the "zones" one are you handling grounds? Are we only looking at the power rails and you are handling ground as a continuous plane on the bottom?

Comment: To be honest, I think this decoupling/bulk capacitance is a bit overkill. One bulk capacitor (maybe 10-100uF depending on the application) and two local capacitors on the input (0.33uF) and output (0.1uF) of the regulator should be perfectly adequate for the current handling capabilities of a basic linear reg.

Comment: Yeah. That's overkill. You can find 200A motor drivers with 1/4 that capacitance.

Comment: Are these caps supposed to be post-rectifier smoothing caps?

Comment: In your second layout, I'd make the track from the 7805 input staright horizontally to the track between the capacitors,rather than zig-zaging it up to the top.  I'd alos maks the tracks considerably wider.  I don't see an output connector.

Comment: The first layout has some issues: It's unclear how this would not be tying all of the positive terminals of the capacitors to ground with the plated-through holes to the ground plane; are there keepouts? The bottom-most capacitor is tied to the fuse and the anode of the diode. You will have a hard time soldering those components without thermal spokes. I can't tell if the "1 GND" texts are silkscreen or only in your layout software, but I would urge you not to label the bottom mounting hole as "GND" because they are too tempting to attach leads to, and mis-labeled test points are a curse.

Comment: If you're trying to reduce loop area between the regulator and the capacitors, you would be better off using physically smaller capacitors (It's only 12V) and rearranging the placement of the caps, fuse, and diode.

Comment: What is the application here?  Output current?  Is the 12V already DC? If so, then you don't likely need hardly any capacitance on the input, 100uF/16V is probably fine.